# How do I schedule recurring jobs in Active Job (Rails 4.2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

I found this  [Schedule one-time jobs in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543505/schedule-one-time-jobs-in-rails)
but this only shows how schedule one-time.  I am interested in scheduling a recurring job.

Delayed_job has this

```
self.delay(:run_at => 1.minute.from_now)
```

How do I do something like that in Rails 4.2/Active Job?

Comment: The DelayedJob example you posted would be one-time job in the future as opposed to a recurring job, which would run over-and-over again. Which do you mean?

Comment: I want one that runs over-and-over again.

Comment: I don't believe there's an ActiveJob api for that. Depending on your background system, there are extensions (https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler, https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron) or just use cron (https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork, https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: As @rossta said, there's no facility for that in ActiveJob. For the most part, anything more advanced than "do this later" still requires directly using the queueing system you've selected.

Comment: As rossta and colinm said, this functionality does not work just with ActiveJob, and in fact, the solutions given below will not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926863/create-recurring-activejob-fails

Answer (score 33):

Similar to rab3's answer, since ActiveJob has support for callbacks, I was thinking of doing something like

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  after_perform do |job|
    # invoke another job at your time of choice 
    self.class.set(:wait => 10.minutes).perform_later(job.arguments.first)
  end

  def perform(the_argument)
    # do your thing
  end
end
```

[activejob callbacks](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#callbacks)

Comment: I like this a little more; feels more rails-like.

Comment: is doing `before_perform` any better ? it will avoid all delays caused by the perform method

Comment: how can I do a conditional retry here?

Answer (score 28):

If you want to delay the job execution to 10 minutes later, two options:

1. `SomeJob.set(wait: 10.minutes).perform_later(record)`
2. `SomeJob.new(record).enqueue(wait: 10.minutes)`

Delay to a specific moment from now use `wait_until`.

1. `SomeJob.set(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon).perform_later(record)`
2. `SomeJob.new(record).enqueue(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon)`

Details please refer to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Base.html.

For recurring jobs, you just put `SomeJob.perform_now(record)` in a cronjob ([whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)).

If you use Heroku, just put  `SomeJob.perform_now(record)` in a scheduled rake task. Please read more about scheduled rake task here: [Heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler).

Comment: Note that `wait_until` expects an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` while `wait` expects an instance of `Date`. Rather, the object passed to `wait_until` needs to respond to `:to_f` and return the "epoch seconds" to which to wait to (seconds since Jan 1 1970)

Answer (score 10):

You can just re-enqueue the job at the end of the execution

```rb
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  RUN_EVERY = 1.hour

  def perform
    # do your thing

    self.class.perform_later(wait: RUN_EVERY)
  end
end
```

Comment: That's actually not a reliable solution : if an exception occurs, the chain breaks, and some backend adapters don't seem to accept ActiveSupport::Duration arguments. You also have to manually launch the jobs the first time.

Comment: @Pak You an always add an `ensure` block on the method level or in a `after_perform` callback.

Comment: We used to do this, it's not reliable for a few reasons. 1) it does not account for the time your job takes. If your job takes 5 min, that's 2 hours every day, which means you run roughly 22 jobs/24 hours. (this is fixable with clock math) 2) there's a chance a job does not run due to a worker being down. If you have a job that looks at "the most recent hour of x" when it runs, it will never catch up. 3) the ensure block isn't guaranteed to run in the case of a bounce. if you're running on heroku, and do a deploy while a job is running, there's a decent chance you kill the process.

Comment: Please don't use this solution, it's not reliable. Even if you have an `ensure` clause to reschedule your job, your process might just crash before it executing it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using resque as your ActiveJob backend, you can use a combination of resque-scheduler's Scheduled Jobs and active_scheduler (https://github.com/JustinAiken/active_scheduler, which wraps the scheduled jobs to work properly with ActiveJob).