# automate sale alert using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation, rubygems

situation:

- Customer click on "wish list" to a product that wanted.
- If the product have discount on it an auto-mail generator will email to that customer saying that product is on sales.

is there any guideline or idea or even a gem that could help me out?

Answer (score 0):

When the customer adds a product to his wishlist, you must store this information in the database in order to retrieve it later.

The main question here is: how do you set that a product is now available?

If you do it from your application, with a form for example, and if you have to request your application, then you can simply run a task in your controller. That way, when you mark a product as available, you just have to search for the persons that put this product in their wishlist and to send them an email (see [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)).

But, if this is not you (or a user) that change the availability state of a product (for example, it's an external program that change the database data), then, you can run a task each x minutes/hours/... to check if wishlisted products are now available. You can give a look at [ActiveJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798013/how-do-i-schedule-recurring-jobs-in-active-job-rails-4-2) for this.