# I need a suitable function from mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I can send a comment to the author of the post with this function.How can I make a function that will send comments to posts for the last hour to the authors of these posts?

I am new to this business

```
class CommentMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def new_comment(comment)
    @comment = comment
    @post = @comment.post
    mail to: @post.user.email, subject: "New comment on your post"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke job when create new post (in controller or somewhere)

```
NewPostCommentsCheckerJob.perform_later(post_id)
```

And define it like this

```
class NewPostCommentsCheckerJob < ApplicationJob
  RUN_EVERY = 1.hour

  def perform(post_id)
    Post.
      find_by(id: post_id).
      comments.
      where(created_at: RUN_EVERY.ago..Time.current).
      find_each do |new_comment|
        CommentMailer.new_comment(new_comment).deliver_later
      end

    self.class.perform_later(post_id, wait: RUN_EVERY)
  end
end
```

It will be invoked every hour, check new comments for last hour and call method of your mailer

Please also look here other ways to reschedule job:

[How do I schedule recurring jobs in Active Job (Rails 4.2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25798013/10608621)

Comment: I don't need to call him every hour. Other things will do it.Check for new comments in the last hour and call your mailout method only.

Comment: you can change it to real??